# Must a line connecting an internal point to and external point of an n-dimensional orthotope intersect a face of the orthotope?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given an $n$-dimensional orthotope and two points, $x_\text{internal}$ and $x_\text{external}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are internal and external to the orthotope respectively, is it necessarily true that the line segment connecting $x_\text{internal}$ and $x_\text{external}$ will intersect a face of the orthotope?

Intuition says "yeah, obviously" but experimentation suggests otherwise.

More info for context:

I'm writing some code to compute that intersection.  I first decompose the orthotope into its $n-1$ facets and, if they have dimensionality 2, I compute the line-plane intersection in $n$-space using the algorithm specified here*: [Line/Plane intersection : in high dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61061/line-plane-intersection-in-high-dimension/61073#61073)

If any has an intersection, I return the point, else I return null.

If they do not, i get the $n-1-1 = n-2$ dimensional facets of the original orthotope and recurse for each, etc.

*I can provide a justification for the steps of the linked algorithm if needed.

One simple test-case that's killing me:

Consider the 4-cube $[0, 1]^4$, the center point $C = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)$, and an external point $E = (2.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)$

Does the line segment $CE$ intersect a face of the 4-cube?  If so, what is the point of intersection?

Obviously it's tough to visualize, but I would expect the line-segment to intersect the side containing (1,0,0,1), (1,1,0,1), and (1,1,1,1)

Regardless, the line-segment seemingly intersects none of the sides.

My first assumption in a situation like this is that I screwed up, but I've been stuck for a while and have MANY unit tests so I'm no longer convinced "yeah, obviously" is the correct answer.

Comment: Normally I would do a routine typesetting correction changing $x_{internal}$ to $x_\text{internal}$, the latter coded as `x_\text{internal}`, but the moderators have been complaining to me to the effect that the number of such contributions from me is too big, and they have been so much less than honest in their communications to me about this that no assurance of any kind from them can be trusted, so I would risk getting banned for helping with this.

Comment: I've made the change.  Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider as a "face" vs. the various "hyperfaces" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie sorry, I mean "face" as the 2D-orthotopes (rectangles) of the boundary of the shape.